# Reading mdy_hms AM/PM off excel into r

Tags: r, date, dplyr, format, lubridate

I am using dplyr and lubridate.

I am using read_excel to export a data.frame into R from excel. In Excel, I have a column that consists of mdy_hms AM or PM. In R, my code consists of:

```
df$dateTimeEtc
```

And this prints out as an example:

```
"2017-03-07 11:10:37 UTC" "2017-03-22 10:04:42 UTC" "2017-03-08 09:36:49 UTC"
```

However, I have tried to use:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(dateTimeEtc = mdy_hms(dateTimeEtc))
```

So that R recognizes these data points in a mdy_hms (not sure what to do to include the AM/PM) format. However, this line of code converts all my data points into NA. Ideally I'd rather R read these data points as ONLY mdy so I can make comparisons with other mdy data points.

Another goal is to find the max and min data points in this column.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you keep all your timeline data in a date or datetime format as long as possible, to enable calculations and sorting. In my experience, `mdy` makes more sense as a formatting choice at the last step, since R does not see `mdy` data as dates at all, but rather as character strings. So you will get unexpected results if you try to calculate anything in `mdy` or visualize it.

```
library(dplyr); library(lubridate)
df = data_frame(dateTimeEtc = c("2017-03-07 11:10:37 UTC", 
                    "2017-03-22 18:04:42 UTC", 
                    "2017-03-08 09:36:49 UTC"))

df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   dateTimeEtc            
#>   <chr>                  
#> 1 2017-03-07 11:10:37 UTC
#> 2 2017-03-22 18:04:42 UTC
#> 3 2017-03-08 09:36:49 UTC


# Convert character to datetime POSIXct (if not already that format),
#  then make a character string in mdy format and 12 hour clock. 
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(dateTimeEtc2 = ymd_hms(dateTimeEtc),
         as_mdy = format(dateTimeEtc2, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))
df2
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   dateTimeEtc             dateTimeEtc2        as_mdy                
#>   <chr>                   <dttm>              <chr>                 
#> 1 2017-03-07 11:10:37 UTC 2017-03-07 11:10:37 03/07/2017 11:10:37 AM
#> 2 2017-03-22 18:04:42 UTC 2017-03-22 18:04:42 03/22/2017 06:04:42 PM
#> 3 2017-03-08 09:36:49 UTC 2017-03-08 09:36:49 03/08/2017 09:36:49 AM
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed - Thank you for your help